# What makes matrix multiplication on both sides of an equation (pre/post multiply) valid?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have always understood matrix multiplication to be that when you multiply, the placement has to be consistent, in that you must pre-multiply or post-multiply both sides of an equation.

Suppose we have that $\mathbf{A}= \mathbf{B}$, then I know that if we have a new matrix $\mathbf{X}$ applied to both sides, it must be either $\mathbf{X}\mathbf{A}= \mathbf{X}\mathbf{B}$ or $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}= \mathbf{B}\mathbf{X}$. What I am failing to understand is why this is valid. Is there a way to prove this without using heavy machinery? Thanks.

Comment: If $a=b$, are you happy to conclude $a-x=b-x$ or $x-a=x-b$ but not $a-x=x-b$?

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are matrices such that $A=B$, then $A$ and $B$ are just two different names for the *same thing*. Looking at it this way, it should be obvious that $AX = BX$ and $XA = XB$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $A = B$ we can substitute $A$ for $B$ and vice versa, hence $AX = BX$ simply by replacing $A$ with $B$. Remember $A$ and $B$ are the same (because $A = B$), just symbolized by two different things.

Answer (score 2):

This is the substitution property of the equality expression $=$ (for any values $a$ and $b$ and any expression $G(x)$, if $a = b$ then $G(a) = G(b)$, provided both sides of the equality of well-formed). It's a property of equality by assumption, and is generally required for equality to be meaningful or useful.

Answer (score 1):

Let $M_n$ denote the set of matrices of order $n$. Fix a matrix $X \in M_n$. Define the function $f_L:M_n \to M_n$ by $f_L(A) = XA$. That is, this function multiplies a matrix $A$ on the left by the fixed matrix $X$. Check that this function is well-defined. That is, for a unique input matrix $A$, there is only one output matrix $XA$.

If $A$ and $B$ are two matrices in $M_n$ and $A = B$, then $f_L(A) = f_L(B)$, since our function is well-defined. Hence $XA = XB$ when $A = B$. This is one of multiple ways to see that this manipulation is legal. Clearly the analogous function $f_R:M_n\to M_n$ defined by $f_R(A) = AX$ enjoys the same properties we are interested in.

Another way to see the manipulation is valid is to consider the matrices as linear transformations. Then, if $A = B$ as functions, applying $X$ to each side of the equation produces the new function $X\circ A = X\circ B$, and these are still equal as maps. Again, the situation is analogous for multiplication on the right.